# How to return a variable to a form onsubmit event?

Tags: javascript, html

Even though the following code is working properly, my boss mentioned that I should return a flag (variable) instead of returning true or false. I understand that part, but my question is how do I get the variable's value within my form. This is my form:

```
<form id="myForm" action="post.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
```

and this is my JavaScript code

```
function validate(){

        if(document.getElementById('postTW').checked || document.getElementById('postFB').checked){

            var twFlag = false;
            var fbFlag = false;
            var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
            var twChecker = document.getElementsByName('twitter[]');
            var fbChecker = document.getElementsByName('fbPages[]');
            for (var i = 0; i < twChecker.length; i++) {
                if(twChecker[i].checked){
                    twFlag = true;
                }




        };
        for (var j = 0; j < fbChecker.length; j++) {
            if(fbChecker[j].checked){
                fbFlag = true;
            }
        };

        if(twFlag === false && fbFlag === false){
            alert("We can't proceed, not enough arguments");
            form.reset();
            return false;
        }
        if (fbFlag === twFlag){
            alert("tw and fb would be posted");
            return true;

        }
        else if (fbFlag === true && twFlag === false)
        {
            alert("only fb would be posted");
            return true;
        }
        else if (fbFlag === false && twFlag === true){
            alert("Only tw would be posted");
            return true;
        }

        else{
            alert("Not enough arguments ");
            form.reset();
            return false;
        }

    }


    else{
        alert("Not enough arguments to submit the form");

        return false;
    }

}
```

Thank you for any advice

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking..

Comment: Comment removed and added as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take an input field of `type="hidden"` like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="myfield" value="your_value">
```

and then use it in JavaScript like this

```
function validate(){
    var temp;
    //code here
    .....

        if(twFlag === false && fbFlag === false){
            alert("We can't proceed, not enough arguments");
            form.reset();
            temp = document.getElementById("myfield").value;
           // assigned value to temp variable, assign true or false as value to temp if you are returning it before form submission
            return temp; //returning temp value
        }
        if (fbFlag === twFlag){
            alert("tw and fb would be posted");
            temp = document.getElementById("myfield").value;
            // assigned value to temp variable, assign true or false as value to temp if you are returning it before form submission
            return temp; //returning temp value

        }
     .....
    }
```

**OR**

you can declare a global variable for your function like this

```
var flag=false;//here I've set default value as false
function validate(){
.....
//code here and use flag variable
//for eg take this part of your code

    if(twFlag === false && fbFlag === false){
        alert("We can't proceed, not enough arguments");
        form.reset();
        flag = false;// assigning value to flag variable
        return flag; //returning flag
    }
    if (fbFlag === twFlag){
        alert("tw and fb would be posted");
        flag = true;// assigning value to flag variable
        return flag; //returning flag

    }
 .....
}
```

Comment: Can you go a little bit further with your explanation please? I still don't understand how the form would catch the flag's value

Comment: @Alexander : check the updated answer.. u got it now?

Comment: I totally understands that, My problem is not that part of the code. I am confused here:  <form id="myForm" action="post.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();"> Flag would be either true or false. How does the form knows the value that is returning?? Thank you for your help, I am an intern and I had to learn JavaScript in my own

Comment: not clear with your this part `how does the form know`? however if you want explanation then its as follows.. when you submit your form `onsubmit` calls your JS function `validate()` if value returned is true then form is submitted else its not. Form doesn't have any idea about what you are doing in the JS function. You have to write code as per your requirement in order to return your value on form submit.

Comment: yeah.. just posted comment and saw the marked answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as an answer to be more specific.

In your form, add:

```
<input type="hidden" name="flagged" id="flagged" value="0">
```

in your validate function:

```
if (fbFlag === twFlag){
            alert("tw and fb would be posted");
document.getElementById("flagged").value = 1;
            return true;

        }
```

Now you have flagged the form as submitted, and you can retrieve that like any other POST on the PHP side.